# How to create a nested Resource path in AWS RestAPI using Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

Can somebody explain the **parentId** property of aws resource type **AWS::ApiGateway::Resource** ?
Documentation can be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-resource.html) , Documentation is very much limited and only shows how to get the rootResourceId. Using that i was able to create the following structure. which gives me these paths.

**/portfolio**

**/resource**

**/{resourceId}**

> ```
> /
>  /portfolio
>    GET
>    OPTIONS
>  /resource
>    GET
>    OPTIONS
>  /{resourceId}
>    GET
>    OPTIONS
> ```

Now my question is how to achieve structure like this where in **{resourceId}** is nested inside **resource**, so that my path looks like **/resource/{resourceId}** .

> ```
> /
>  /portfolio
>    GET
>    OPTIONS
>  /resource
>    GET
>    OPTIONS
>    /{resourceId}
>      GET
>      OPTIONS
> ```

This is my template that create resources

```
    "getPortfoliosResource": {
        "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource",
        "Properties": {
            "RestApiId": {
                "Ref": "myAPI"
            },
            "ParentId": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": ["myAPI", "RootResourceId"]
            },
            "PathPart": "portfolios"
        }
    },
    "getResourcesResource": {
        "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource",
        "Properties": {
            "RestApiId": {
                "Ref": "myAPI"
            },
            "ParentId": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": ["myAPI", "RootResourceId"]
            },
            "PathPart": "resources"
        }
    },
   "getResourceid": {
        "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource",
        "Properties": {
            "RestApiId": {
                "Ref": "epmoliteAPI"
            },
            "ParentId": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": ["epmoliteAPI", "RootResourceId"]
            },
            "PathPart": "{resourceId}"
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The ParentId needs to reference the Resource you want to put it in.

```
"getPortfoliosResource": {
  "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource",
  "Properties": {
      "RestApiId": {
          "Ref": "myAPI"
      },
      "ParentId": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": ["myAPI", "RootResourceId"]
      },
      "PathPart": "portfolios"
  }
},
"getResourcesResource": {
  "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource",
  "Properties": {
      "RestApiId": {
          "Ref": "myAPI"
      },
      "ParentId": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": ["myAPI", "RootResourceId"]
      },
      "PathPart": "resources"
  }
},
"getResourceid": {
  "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource",
  "Properties": {
      "RestApiId": {
          "Ref": "myAPI"
      },
      "ParentId": {
          "Ref": "getResourcesResource"
      },
      "PathPart": "{resourceId}"
  }
},
```

Comment: yes, actually figured that out, when i checked serverless compiled script, while trying i was doing a silly mistake by passing 'Ref' as 'ref' . Thank you!